# Transferring files from parent folder to multiple subfolders

Tags: powershell, file, transfer

I have 200,000 documents in a parent folder, and I'm trying to figure out how to move them so that the first subfolder receives 500 documents, then the next folder, 500, etc until all files are moved. I have 400 subfolders, sequentially named `PXDOX (1)`, `PXDOX (2)` and so on.

Brute force copying is taking forever, so if any of you have a solution, I would be very grateful to hear your ideas.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. What are the issues with your current code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To make the most out of Stack Overflow, please only ask specific questions about code you've already written. This question is very open ended which makes it less likely to be answered. I recommend checking out the [PowerShell Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/), as they are extremely well written and helpful, and try scripting a solution yourself. If you have any questions with your code after you've had a crack at it, please come back and ask another question. Have a good day!

Comment: This is a fairly simple script to implement. Make use of the `Test-Path`, `New-Item`, and `Move-Item` cmdlets. If you have a go at writing one we can help fix any errors, but SO isn't really a "write my script for me" kinda place.